# Can anyone explain how custom comparator works in C++?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, data-structures

**Ques**: Given an array of linked-lists lists, each linked list is sorted in ascending order.
Merge all the linked-lists into one sort linked-list and return it.

```
Input: lists = [[1,4,5],[1,3,4],[2,6]]
Output: [1,1,2,3,4,4,5,6]
Explanation: The linked-lists are:
[
  1->4->5,
  1->3->4,
  2->6
]
merging them into one sorted list:
1->1->2->3->4->4->5->6
```

I don't understand how this custom comparator is working for min-heap priority_queue.

```
/*
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * struct ListNode {
 *     int val;
 *     ListNode *next;
 *     ListNode(int x) : val(x), next(NULL) {}
 * };
 */
class Solution {
public:
    ListNode* mergeKLists(vector<ListNode*>& lists) {
        priority_queue<ListNode*, vector<ListNode*>, comp> pq;
        for(auto head : lists){
            if(head != NULL)
                pq.push(head);
        }
        ListNode* dummy = new ListNode(-1);
        ListNode* curr = dummy;
        while(!pq.empty()){
            curr->next = pq.top();
            pq.pop();
            curr = curr->next;
            ListNode* next = curr->next;
            if(next != NULL)
                pq.push(next);
        }
        return dummy->next;
    }
    
    struct comp{
        bool operator()(ListNode* a, ListNode* b){
            return a->val > b->val;
        }  
    };
};
```

Why the return val is `a->val > b->val` instead of `a->val < b->val`

Comment: You could just use `std::merge`

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili: `std::merge` doesn't understand their `ListNode` object.

Comment: @BillLynch `std::merge` does work with a comparator too

Comment: @BillLynch on a second thought, they would also need a custom iterator type. So, it's a bit more work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[std::priority_queue is documented on cppreference with:](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue)

> A user-provided Compare can be supplied to change the ordering, e.g. using `std::greater<T>` would cause the smallest element to appear as the `top()`.

So if you want to have a priority queue where you can pop the smallest element, it expects you to pass a comparator that returns true if `a > b`.

(And note that you're leaking the object allocated at `dummy`)